# Redefining a predefined errno error message (E2BIG)

Tags: c++, errno, strerror

Is there a way to redefine `errno` error messages? For example, I am working with `E2BIG` and I am wanting to change the error message it shows when the error is encountered.

These messages are stored as an `int`, so when I redefine it will only let me change its integer value which is not very useful. I am wanting to change the message itself.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() 
{
   const std::size_t BUF_SIZE = 256;
   std::vector<char> buffer(BUF_SIZE);
   int errNum = E2BIG;

   auto strerror = strerror_s(buffer.data(), buffer.size(), errNum);

   std::cout << buffer.data();
}
```

The current error message is:

> Arg list too long

But I am trying to change it to say something a bit different. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to write a wrapper function to fill in any custom error messages you need.  For example:

```
errno_t my_strerror_s(char *buffer, size_t numberOfElements, int errnum)
{
    if (errnum==E2BIG) {
        const char *msg = "my custom error";
        if (numberOfElements < strlen(msg)+1) {
            return -1;
        else {
            strcpy(buffer, msg);
            return 0;
        }
    } else {
        return strerror_s(buffer, numberOfElements, errnum);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a nice way to do this. If I, in any case, need to pass E2BIG to another function (one that cannot be changed) that calls strerror_s, then the E2BIG message itself would need to be the custom error message. Do you know if it is possible to redefine the message of E2BIG itself?

Comment: @BrentMB It is not possible.